# ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '73d16e93' at 'null' in 'null'

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

I am using log4j2 the jar files are following:
log4j-api-2.14.0.jar
log4j-core-2.14.0.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.0.jar

Executing the following line:
LogManager.getLogger("com.foo.Bar1");

using the following VM argument:
-Dlog4j.configuration=test1.xml

The config file test1.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console1" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="test1.txt">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.foo.Bar1" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console1" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

the following error  occurs when the java file started
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '73d16e93' at 'null' in 'null'

i understand "-Dlog4j.configuration=test1.xml" is wrong. "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=test1.xml" is correct. but i do not understand why the error appears when "-Dlog4j.configuration=test1.xml" is used.

Why the error occurs when -Dlog4j.configuration=test1.xml is used.

Answer (score 66):

This is because the `log4j.configuration` expects the file to be in the **classpath**, while `log4j.configurationFile` (`log4j2.configurationFile` for log4j2) expects it as a **file path**.

If you add `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` to the VM arguments, you can see which file it is trying to load and will print its path. That way, you will have an indication of why the error is happening.

Comment: Use `log4j2.configurationFile` instead of `log4j.configurationFile`.

Answer (score 13):

This was exactly the same cryptic error I had, so I updated my VM parameters to

`-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=`

Instead of

`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=`

and it solved the issue

notice the **2** in the Dlog4j**2**

Comment: in my case it did not help; my dependencies are like this: ``` <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Log4j 2 has experimental support for Log4j 1.2 configuration files. If you specify -Dlog4j.configuration then Log4j's ConfigurationFactory assumes you want to run in compatibility mode and looks for a configuration file in Log4j 1.x format. If you have provided a file in Log4j2 format obviously that is going to fail, especially if you don't have log4j-1.2-api in your project as that is where the configuration class for Log4j 1.x XML configuration files is.

Answer (score 1):

this problem may occur if you don't have write access to the xml file (a bug from library ? you should only need read access in theory).

dummy workaround : make a copy of this xml file to a location where you have write access and point to it

Comment: Thank you so much, adding write permission fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of getting the same issue it was caused by incorrect log4j file specified

**INCORRECT**
LOGGING_OPTIONS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=***log4j2-sim***.xml -Dlog.directory=${STDOUT_DIR}"

**CORRECT**
LOGGING_OPTIONS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=**log4j2.xml** -Dlog.directory=${STDOUT_DIR}"